# check type of element in stl container - c++

Tags: c++, stl, types, containers

how can i get the type of the elements that are held by a STL container?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do here?  Since C++ is statically typed, you should generally know what type the elements are (vector<int>, for example, holds ints).  If you'd explain why you don't know what the types are, and what you want to use them for, that would help answer the question.

Comment: @David Thornley: `template <typename T> void foo(std::template<T> arg){ /* Here, we don't know what the elements type is */ }`  I think it's a pretty common situation.

Comment: @Jalf: At that point true. But at that point foo() is only a concept. But as soon as you use foo() you also know the type.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For containers in general it will be `X::value_type`. For associative containers it will be `X::mapped_type` (`X::value_type` corresponds to `pair<const Key,T>`). It is according to Chapter 23 of C++ Standard.

To check that types are equal you could use [`boost::is_same`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html). And since C++11 — [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

Comment: Update: we now have [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

Answer (score 22):

```
container::value_type
```

Comment: ok that's already great, but i can't seem compare two value types returned by container::value_type. any suggestions?

Comment: @Patrick: you can't compare the "values returned by value_type" because value_type is a type, not a value. Comparing two value_types is thus a static operation, not a runtime one. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may want to look at "is_same" in Boost.TypeTraits: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html

Comment: @Patrick: You asked for the *type* of elements stored in the vector, not the *value* of the elements. You can compare the values, you can't compare types (at least not without a lot of metaprogramming tricks) - perhaps you should explain what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Maybe need to add typename?

Answer (score 5):

Checking whether two types are the same can be achieved like this (without RTTI, value is usable at compile-time):

```
template <class T, class U>
struct same_type
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

//specialization for types that are the same
template <class T>
struct same_type<T, T>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

//sample usage:
template <class FirstContainer, class SecondContainer>
bool containers_of_same_type(const FirstContainer&, const SecondContainer&)
{
    return same_type<
        typename FirstContainer::value_type, 
        typename SecondContainer::value_type
    >::value;
}

#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << containers_of_same_type(std::vector<int>(), std::list<int>());
    std::cout << containers_of_same_type(std::vector<char>(), std::list<int>());
}
```

(This is basically how `boost::is_same` works, minus workarounds for certain compilers.)

Answer (score 1):

A user defined container type - call it `ContainerType` - that supports `ContainerType::begin ()`, and `ContainerType::end ()` methods could use, in C++ 20,

```
using DataType = std::ranges::range_value_t<ContainerType>;
```

to reference the type of data if needed. Here's an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct MyContainer
{   
    T * begin () { return m_Arr.data (); }
   
    T * end () { return m_Arr.data () + m_Arr.size (); }
   
    std::array<T, N> m_Arr;
};

template <typename ContainerType> std::vector<std::ranges::range_value_t<ContainerType>> ToVector (ContainerType cc)
{
    using DataType = std::ranges::range_value_t<ContainerType>;
    std::vector<DataType> res;
    for (const auto &value: cc)
    {
        res.push_back (value);
    }
    
    return res;
}


int main ()
{
    MyContainer<double, 4> cc{{0.5, 1., 2., 3.}};
    const auto myVector = ToVector (cc);
    
    for (auto vv: myVector)
        std::cout << vv << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In what sense? 
Maybe using RTTI and typeid()?

Probably you have to use container::valuetype where container is the name of your container (for example std::vector)

Alek

Answer (score 0):

You need to give us more context.  If you mean you want the value known at compiletime so it's easy to change it then use `container::value_type`.

```
typedef vector<int> coordinates;

coordinates seq;
fib::value_type elem = seq.back(); // it's easy to change int type
```

If what you mean is that the container may hold various concrete (derived) types and you wish to know them at runtime then you should probably re-evaluate your approach.  In object-oriented programming hiding the type at runtime is sometimes a powerful approach, because it means you make fewer assumptions about what you're working with.  You can of course use RTTI, but there's probably a better way:  we'd need more context to tell.

If you wish to compare types then you're probably heading the runtime path.  C++ supports polymorphism, which is essentially that type-comparison you're looking after -- but built into the language.  You want to execute a different set of instructions based on the type?  Polymorphism allows you to execute a different function based on the type of the object.  You need not write a single extra line of code -- only derive from a common base.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
if (typeid(yourVariable)==typeid(YourClass)) //...
```

Alek

Comment: or dynamic_cast<> if you would like to test inheritance chain ;)

Comment: but only if your type has virtual methods.

Comment: dynamic_cast is used on polymorphic pointers of course. I didn't mention it. You are right. Thanks for pointing it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

given the types are known statically you can check they are the same statically without using rtti by using template specialization. e.g. use something like http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html or if boost isn't available roll your own