# How to get the type of elements in a container?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a vector like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
```

Then I want to know the type of `vec`'s elements. How can I get it? Too bad `decltype(vec[0])` results in `int&`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check type of element in stl container - c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708867/check-type-of-element-in-stl-container-c)

Comment: The VS2010 bug is [c++ - How to get element type from STL container instance? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391814/how-to-get-element-type-from-stl-container-instance)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
std::vector<int>::value_type
```

You can also use

```
std::remove_reference<decltype(vec[0])>::type
```

to get rid of the reference.

Another option is to use `decltype(vec)::value_type`. However, this doesn't [currently work](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/757545/cannot-use-decltype-before-scope-operator) on Visual Studio due to a compiler bug. A workaround for that compiler is to create an intermediate `typedef`.

```
typedef decltype(vec) vec_type;
vec_type::value_type foo;
```

Comment: It would be better if there is something like `decltype(vec)::value_type`.

Comment: @Mike That does work. You're using MSVC aren't you? There's a bug in the compiler that causes errors if you write `::` after any `decltype` expression.

Comment: Another workaround for MSVC is using std::identity<decltype(vec)>::type::value_type

Comment: @GalDude33 `std::identity` is non-standard. It appeared in some pre-standardization C++0x drafts but was dropped somewhere along the way.

Comment: std::identity does exist in VS (checked on VS2010) - where a bug denies you simply writing decltype(vec)::value_type

Answer (score 0):

For object, `c`, of any container type including [arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) and all standard library [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) such as [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list):

`typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::begin(c))>::type`