# const_cast doesn't work with std::remove_reference

Tags: c++, constants

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to achieve

```cpp
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 5>* arr = new std::array<int, 5>{}; // no fill
    int** temp = new int*;

    for (const auto& e : *arr) {
        // some code that uses e...
        *temp = const_cast< std::remove_reference<decltype(e)>* >(&e); //error
        *temp = const_cast< int* >(&e); //ok
    }

    **temp = 22;
}
```

I need to access the type of `e` with `decltype`, and also to point to `e`, so I remove the reference from the decl type and declare it with a pointer.

But it doesn't work and treats `std::remove_reference` as a class `invalid 'const_cast' from type 'const int*' to type 'std::remove_reference<const int&>*'`

How can I fix it?

Comment: What's the point of casting `&e` to the exact type it already has? Besides, `e` is an `int*` pointer (to the first approximation, with some const qualifiers removed for clarity). `&e` is `int**`. `*temp` is an `int*`. You are trying to assign a double pointer to a single pointer - that ain't gonna work, const or no const. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but it's clear you've miscounted your stars somewhere along the way.

Comment: Even if this worked, you'd have problems because `temp` is uninitialized so accessing `*temp` is undefined behavior. Also, even aside from the `const` issue, `&e` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. `*temp` is just a pointer to an `int`. Your usage of pointers has made this code much more confusing.

Comment: Btw. **there is no need to use `fill` just write** `std::array<int*, 5>* arr = new std::array<int*, 5>{}`. Misuse of cast spotted!

Comment: The typo is `std::remove_reference` -> `std::remove_reference_t`. Then you have a separate error of `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(e)>*` being `const int*`.

Comment: Another side note, 9 out of 10 times a const cast means you're breaking some kind of design, and thus const_cast is usually a code smell. The only times I ever have needed it is when something is definitly const from C++ (api) view, but some 3rd party api forgot a const parameter. And in those cases it is sometimes safer to make copy then use a const cast (unless you can prove that api really doesn't change the value ever)

Comment: It looks like the original problem is a specific case of the more abstract [How to get the type of elements in a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16503891)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decltype(&e)` gives you *exactly* the type of the expression `&e` with the value category translated to the matching reference-qualification.

So the cast `const_cast<decltype(&e)>(&e)` doesn't do anything. It casts `&e` which has type `int* const*` and value category prvalue to type `int* const*`, i.e. `const_cast<decltype(&e)>(&e)` is an expression that itself has type `int* const*` and value category prvalue and the result has the same value as `&e`.

If you want to remove the `const`, you want a cast to `int**`, not `int* const*`. You need to remove the `const` from the type, e.g. with `std::remove_cvref_t` you can remove reference and `const` qualification from `e`'s declared type (which is what `decltype(e)` will return):

```
*temp = const_cast<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(e)>*>(&e);
```

However, this is dangerous. Someone might change `*arr` to be an object that is non-modifiable and then the compiler won't give you any warning or error anymore, because the `const_cast` suppresses it. Then you'll have undefined behavior.

If you need the reference to be const *most* of the time, it is better to start with a non-`const` reference and then add a `const` one for the scope where it should be `const`:

```
for (auto& e_modifiable : *arr) {
    {
        const auto& e = e_modifiable;
        // some code that uses e...
    }
    // *temp was probably unintended. It has the wrong type and
    // temp is uninitialized. However `**temp = 22;` also is UB
    // because all elements of the array are null pointers.
    temp = &e_modifiable; // error
}
```

Also note other comments about your code under your question which are valid. All in all I suspect that you are using way too many pointers and `new` for what you are trying to do, although there isn't enough context to know what exactly that is.

Comment: `std::remove_cvref_t` fixed the issue. what does `cv` stand for?

Comment: @baronsec `cv` for _cv-qualifiers_, i.e. `c` for `const` and `v` for `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, there is no need to use `std::array::fill` when you can use:

```
//------------------------------------------------vv-->use zero initialization
std::array<int*, 5>* arr = new std::array<int*, 5>{}; 
//no need to use fill here
```

---

Now coming to the error:

> Why doesn't it work?

Because a) your use of the `const_cast` to remove the `const` is incorrect. Also you're casting `&e` to the type it already has. You might have omitted the cast altogether if this is what was needed.

More importantly, even if there was no low-level const, and we had just `int**` instead of `int* const*`, still an expression of type `int**` could not be assigned to an expression of type `int*` as there is no conversion possible between the two(both explicit or implicit).

---

Also note that `temp` is uninitialized so `*temp` is **undefined behavior**.