# How to check type of container using template struct instead of function?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

In this post [check type of element in stl container - c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708867/check-type-of-element-in-stl-container-c) user UncleBens showed how to check the type of a container using a struct `same_type` and a function `containers_of_same_type`

Im trying to do the same thing, except, instead of using a function for checking the containers, I want to use a struct.  I have the following code, but it is giving me errors:

```
// Working
template<typename X, typename Y>
struct SameType {
    enum { result = 0 };
};

// Working
template<typename T>
struct SameType<T, T> {
    enum { result = 1 };
};

// This struct is not working
template<typename C1, typename C2>
struct SameContainerType {
    enum { value = SameType<typename C1::value_type, typename C2::value_type>::result };
};

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::cout << SameType<int, int>::result << std::endl;;     // 1
    std::cout << SameType<int, double>::result << std::endl;;  // 0
    std::cout << SameContainerType<std::vector<int>(), std::list<int>()>::value;  // error
}
```

The error is, `C1` and `C2` must be a namespace or class to use `::`

Comment: Using enums to define values inside your structs is old and obsolete. You can use `static constexpr` variables instead.

Comment: I'm new to this stuff.  Thank you for the input, I'll take that into consideration.

Comment: also, just inherit from `std:true_type` and false type.  All the cool kids do it.  `template<typename X, typename Y>
struct SameType:std::false_type{};`; instead of `result` it exposes `value`, and instances have a bunch of `constexpr` operations as well.

Comment: Yea I've seen that inheritance pattern when I was watching introductory lectures but it was still new to me, I will incorporate it into my structs.  Ty for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<int>()` is a function which returns a `std::vector<int>`. You need to remove the `()`.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << SameType<int, int>::result << std::endl;;     // 1
    std::cout << SameType<int, double>::result << std::endl;;  // 0
    std::cout << SameContainerType<std::vector<int>, std::list<int>>::value; // 1
}
```