# How to pass an instance of a container as a type name to a template struct?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Thanks to user Dark Falcon's answer on my question [How to check type of container using template struct instead of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66617259/how-to-check-type-of-container-using-template-struct-instead-of-function), I got the `SameContainerType` struct to work, but now, if I try to pass an instance of an STL container to it, it doesn't work:

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
struct SameType {
    enum { result = 0 };
};

template<typename T>
struct SameType<T, T> {
    enum { result = 1 };
};

template<typename C1, typename C2>
struct SameContainerType {
    enum { value = SameType<typename C1::value_type, typename C2::value_type>::result };
};

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::cout << SameType<int, int>::result << std::endl;;     // 1
    std::cout << SameType<int, double>::result << std::endl;;  // 0
    std::cout << SameContainerType<std::vector<int>, std::list<int>>::value << std::endl; // 1

    // Below does not work
    std::vector<int> vector1;
    std::vector<int> vector2;
    std::cout << SameContainerType<vector1, vector2>::value << std::endl; // error
}
```

The error is: `vector1` and `vector2` are not type names.  How would I pass these instances as type names?

Comment: Maybe `SameContainerType<decltype(vector1), decltype(vector2)>::value` ?

Comment: Well, why do you think you could pass an instance of an object where a typename is expected?

Comment: Off topic: I hope you know that, starting from C++11, there is `std::is_same` that is a standard version of your `SameType`.

Comment: @max66 your answer works.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm just testing some template metaprogramming for my c++ course, I'll most likely use std::is_same in the end.  if its not obvious, i'm a novice at c++, sorry for the weird and easy question.